# C# : We application : Where to store generated PDF files?

Tags: c#, azure, pdf, storage, azure-storage

I am developing web application **(Hosted on azure cloud service)** which is generating PDF. Those PDFs, have to be store at some place because it will get downloaded later. So where to store those files ?

Right now storing it in 'Content' folder of project but issue is when I publish site again 'Content' folder gets empty.

So, having issue with storing files. What is the best way to store it ? To store it in DB or anywhere in cloud services. Can not use azure storage, client don't want to use it.

Please help me with issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37168851/save-generated-pdf-file-in-azure

Comment: Can't use Azure storage

Comment: What is the reason for that?

Comment: Store it in a Azure database then.

Comment: You could use a FTP-Server, or maybe checkout the storage-solutions from amazon

Comment: Due to cost issue client don't want to use it

Comment: Hosting it on the web server itself is not optimal. a) Now you can run your app on only one server. b) You better hope that web server never gets killed and you lose the files on its file system.

Comment: Has the client actually modelled what the cost would be?

Comment: If your folder will be empty because republish, why not create a folder outside of the wwwroot folder?

Comment: For cloud service, when you publish site its formatting whole drive on(which site is hosted) so can't set folder

Answer (score 2):

Using storage is best practice, and it has a lower cost per GB than most other options in Azure. If the costs at scale are a problem, there are options to move files from [hot to cool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-storage-tiers) storage to reduce the per GB cost as data builds up.

You do need to store them in some sort of persistent storage, which Cloud Services does not offer. A database would work, as would deploying the application to a regular VM rather than Cloud Services. [App Services](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system) has persistent storage, as the files are stored in Azure Storage and not on the VM, if that is an option. There are plenty of other options, and any sort of file share will work.