# 404 Error when trying to upload a generated pdf file to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-blob-storage

This is the error I am getting: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: 'The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

On the following code:

**First method for PDF Generation using PDFSharp:**

```
[Route("cpd-services/generate-generic-sla/{cpd_services_id}/{userid}")]
    public ActionResult GenerateGenericClientSLA(int cpd_services_id, int userId)
    {
        var genericSLA = m_cpdServicesRepository.GetCPDServicesGenericSubscriptionDetail(cpd_services_id, userId);

        string SLAContent = m_cpdServicesRepository.GetSLATemplateByType(CPDServicesSLAHelpers.GenericClientDraftSLA);

        SLAContent = InsertGenericSLAData(SLAContent, genericSLA);

        var SLATitle = "GenericSLA" + "-" + userId;

        PdfDocument document = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(SLAContent, PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);
        PdfGenerateConfig config = new PdfGenerateConfig();
        config.PageSize = PdfSharp.PageSize.A4;
        var file = File(PDF.PDFDocumentToBytes(document), "application/pdf");
        file.FileDownloadName = SLATitle.ToLower() + ".pdf";

        return UploadGenericSLA(file, userId, cpd_services_id, SLATitle);
    }
```

**UploadGenericSLA Method:**

```
public JsonResult UploadGenericSLA(FileContentResult file, int userId, int CPDServicesId, string sla)
    {
        Storage storage = new Storage(Settings);

        string filename = storage.UploadPDFDocument(file, "documents/cpd-services-service-level-agreement/generic/cpd-" + CPDServicesId + "/" + sla.Trim().ToLower() + ".?");

        int result = m_cpdServicesRepository.AddCPDServicesGenericSLA(file.FileDownloadName.Trim().ToLower(), CPDServicesSLAHelpers.GenericClientDraftSLA, userId, CPDServicesId);

        if (result > 0)
        {
            TempData[CRUDResult.CRUDMessage] = $"{CRUDResult.Success}|SLA has been successfully generated";
            new TelemetryHelper { }.TrackTrace($"SLA Generation - {CPDServicesId}", Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.SeverityLevel.Information);
            return Json(result);
        }
        else
        {
            TempData[CRUDResult.CRUDMessage] = $"{CRUDResult.Failed}|SLA Generation Failed";
            return Json(result);
        }
    }
```

Which in turn triggers this method on my Storage.cs class:

```
public string UploadPDFDocument(FileContentResult file, string filename)
    {
        return UploadPDFFile($"{Settings.StoragePath}/{Settings.Environment}", file, filename);
    }

protected string UploadPDFFile(string container, FileContentResult file, string filename)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Settings.AzureStorageConnectionString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(container.ToLower());


        if (filename.EndsWith(".?"))
        {
            int pos = file.FileDownloadName.LastIndexOf(".");
            filename = (filename.Substring(0, filename.Length - 1) + file.FileDownloadName.Substring(pos + 1)).ToLower();
        }

        CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename.ToLower());

        blob.Properties.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        blob.SetProperties(); //This is where the request to the blob storage fails.

        blob.Metadata.Add("ContentType", "application/pdf");
        blob.Metadata.Add("Size", file.FileContents.Length.ToString());
        blob.Metadata.Add("ContentLength", file.FileContents.Length.ToString());
        blob.Metadata.Add("Filename", filename);

        if (FileExists(container, filename))
        {
            blob.CreateSnapshot();
        }

        blob.UploadFromByteArray(file.FileContents, 0, file.FileContents.Length);

        return filename;
    }
```

**This is the code for FileExists method:**

```
protected bool FileExists(string container, string filename)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Settings.AzureStorageConnectionString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(container);

        CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

        return blob.Exists();
    }
```

We currently using WindowsAzure.Storage - Company does not want to upgrade as yet...

Any help will be of much appreciation

Comment: Where in your code are you getting this error? Please include code for FileExists method as well.

Comment: @GauravMantri so I have added the code for the FileExists method, I have added a comment next to blob.SetProperties(); this is where I am getting the 404 error

Comment: And if I take the blob.properties.ContentType out, my file gets save a octet/stream instead of application/pdf

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621664/uploading-blockblob-and-setting-contenttype/24622986#24622986.

Comment: @GauravMantri thank you sir, I will most definitely give that a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may  exculde  blob.SetProperties() method.

Try that ,If that doesn’t work  try setting Blobhttpheaders for the content type .
Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621664/uploading-blockblob-and-setting-contenttype/24622986#24622986) thread for the possible solutions  as suggested by @Gaurav Mantri.

Also try to split  properties into two steps ([reference](https://community.dynamics.com/365/financeandoperations/f/dynamics-365-for-finance-and-operations-forum/380031/how-to-set-content-type-of-file-uploaded-to-azure-blob-container))

BlobProperties blobProperties = blockblob.Properties;

blobProperties.ContentType = "application/pdf";

[Other reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37168851/save-generated-pdf-file-in-azure)